# Remove characters from every line of a file in shell

Tags: shell, file, ksh

I have a shell script which is reading the value of a variable line by line. I need to remove certain characters from every line.

What I have - 
$sample_variable -

```
Data 0 start; 1 ABCD0;2 EFGH0;3 IJKL0;4 MNOP0;5 QRST0;6 end;
```

What I want -

```
start
ABCD0
EFGH0
IJKL0
MNOP0
QRST0
end
```

Code that I have written -

```
IFS=$';' 
for j in $sample_variable
do  
    j=$j | cut -d ' ' -f3-
    echo $j
    j=${j// /''}
    echo $j
    echo $j >> output.txt
done
```

I am writing the output in a txt file.But, the file is getting written as output.txt -

```
start
1ABCD0
2EFGH0
3IJKL0
4MNOP0
5QRST0
6end
```

How do I remove the numbers occuring at the beginning also?

Comment: Please write your expected output.

Comment: Please use code blocks formatting for input and output files also. The code you posted is invalid, it shouldn't generate any output. `for j in $sample_variable` splits the input on whitespaces, `j=$j | cut -d ' ' -f3-` just sets the `j=$j`, which outputs nothing, and executes `cut` which reads from stdin. Probably you meant to use `$( ... )` command substitution. `the file is getting written` - how is the file getting written like that? What is the content of `sample_variable`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Please have a look. I have made few changes in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solves the problem -

```
i=0
IFS=$';' 
for j in $sample_variable
do 
    j=${j// /''}
    j=$(echo "$j" | tr -d [$i] | tr -d ["\n"])
    echo "$j" >> output.txt
    i=$((i+1))
done
}
```

So, I have taken a variable 'i' that will keep iterating through the loop. Using that variable I am able to remove the digits occuring only in the beginning of every line.

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to remove all the digits I would say you could try using the `tr` tool, like so:

`IFS=$';' 
for j in $sample_variable
do 
    j=$j | cut -d ' ' -f3-
    echo $j
    j=${j// /''}
    echo $j | tr -d [:digit:]
    echo $j | tr -d [:digit:] >> output.txt
done`

However if you want to only remove the initial digits you'll need a more versatile tool like `sed`, it would look like:

`IFS=$';' 
for j in $sample_variable
do 
    j=$j | cut -d ' ' -f3-
    echo $j
    j=${j// /''}
    echo $j | sed -e 's/^[0-9]\?//'
    echo $j | sed -e 's/^[0-9]\?//' >> output.txt
done`

Comment: It is doing kind of what I want. I have edited my question. can you please check on it once? There are digits in the data also that i want.

Comment: @TeeKay, if you want to only delete the digits if they are the 1st character in the line you would probably need to use `sed` and not `tr`. If that is the case I can try to whip something up.

Comment: I was able to do the whipping using the answer you gave. Will be posting my answer. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find `sed` handy as well,

```
sample_data="Data 0 start 1 ABCD0;2 EFGH0;3 IJKL0;4 MNOP0;5 QRST0;6 end"
sed -e 's/^[^0]*0\ //' -e 's/;/\n/g' -e 's/\(^[^0-9][^0-9]*\ \)/\1\n/' -e 's/\ //g'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sample_data="Data 0 start 1 ABCD0;2 EFGH0;3 IJKL0;4 MNOP0;5 QRST0;6 end"
> echo "$sample_data" |
> sed -e 's/^[^0]*0\ //' -e 's/;/\n/g' -e 's/\(^[^0-9][^0-9]*\ \)/\1\n/' -e 's/\ //g'
start
1ABCD0
2EFGH0
3IJKL0
4MNOP0
5QRST0
6end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove everything in front of the space too:

```
j=${j//* /''}
```

The `''` are unneded.

```
j=${j//* /}
```

The `*` matches any number of any characters. So if `j` has two spaces, then it will remove everything in front and including the second space. Depending on you needs it may be better to use:

```
j=${j##* }
```

or

```
j=${j#* }
```

See [shell parameter expansion in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

It may be better to read the variable in an array and then process it:

```
sample_variable='1 ABCD;2 EFGH;3 IJKL;4 MNOP;5 QRST;'
IFS=';' read -r -a arr <<<"$sample_variable"
```

Then you can split the variable ignoring the anything in front the first space:

```
for j in "${arr[@]}"; do
     j=${j//* /}
     echo "$j"
done
```

But I would just do the following, but it will leave one empty trailing newline, so it may be needed to `sed '$d'` - remove last line:

```
<<<"$sample_variable" tr ';' '\n' | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed '$d'
```

Notes:

- `j=$j | cut -d ' ' -f3-` doesn't do what you think it does. It executes `j=$j` which sets the variable to itself. Then it executes `cut -d ' ' -f3-` with no input, because the assignment doesn't print any output.
- Remember to always quote your variable expansions.

Comment: `<<<"$sample_variable"`, I don't think ksh has *herestrings*?